# Yii: DataProvider pagination is not following url rules defined in config

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I'm listing users on my website with pagination of 15 users per page. It works just fine and  I've re write the url like this.

```
 'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'people' => 'Users/index',
             ...
---
```

As you can see I re route **users/index** to **people**. When I create a url it just also works fine but this isn't working in dataprovider pagination as I'm using CListView to render users list. It creates url in the pagination like this: **users/index/users_pagination/2** how to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

you may like this,

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'people/*' => 'users/index',
            ---
```

Comment: THanks for the answer. It generates url what I needed but pagination has stopped working. It adds url something like this after first click:  **`http://localhost/site/people/2?ajax=yw0&pages=2`**

Comment: if Users is controller and index is action then in your link example what is "site" ?

Comment: site is an application. i.e. c:/wamp/www/site where my website is placed in localhost.